# How do i convert a PDF sent through a secure link (proofpoint) so that it can be printed and edited?

Tags: pdf

On Lenovo laptop. Pdf is from my workplace secure sight. I want to print the pdf. I can't open Acrobat even though it is on my computer. Can I get some help on how to print? Do I need to download it first? How?

Comment: You need to ask your workplace. This in an information security site.